# Overriding ctrl-= in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a basic online graphics editor, and I want to override the browser zoom, when the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (that is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key followed by the <kbd>=</kbd> key) I want the canvas to get larger (I'll handle this via an event), but any attempt to capture this key combination causes my event to fire and then the page to resize anyway. How do I avoid the browser continuing to resize my browser?

I tried this with other keycodes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> does not fire the browser save if I override it for example.

I realise this isn't an amazing usability idea generally, but in the given context of a design application I believe it to be ok.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you return `false` from your event handler?

Comment: Don't break the user's expectations, *ever*.

Comment: @Nick Craver unless you have a *really* good reason. And even then there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can capture it - how about telling the user just to use `+`?

Comment: +1 Indeed use `+`. I would even say that this kind of functionality is expected on `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two resources:

[jQuery plugin: js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about)

[Quirksmode: Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

Be careful to not step on key combinations used by the browser...